# Are all formal schemes *really* Ind-schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, schemes

$\newcommand\LRS{\mathsf{LRS}}\newcommand\FormalSch{\mathsf{FormalSch}}\DeclareMathOperator\Spf{Spf}\newcommand\IndSch{\mathsf{IndSch}}\newcommand\ALRS{\mathsf{ALRS}}\newcommand\FSch{\mathsf{FSch}}$I'm trying to understand whether there's a fully faithful functor $\LRS \supset \FormalSch \to \IndSch$ and in what sense. Here's my progress so far:

Let $\mathsf{A}$ be the category of adic rings. The objects are topological rings whose topology is generated by a descending filtration of ideals whose intersection is $\{0\}$. Morphisms are continuous homomorphism of rings.

There's a functor $\Spf: \mathsf{A} \to \IndSch$ which takes an adic ring to the formal spectrum which is naturally a filtered colimit of (affine) schemes). The target of the functor could be that of *adic* locally ringed spaces (topological spaces with sheaves of adic rings and morphisms between for which the comorphism of sheaves is continuous). Denote this category $\ALRS$.

In $\ALRS$ we have an adjunction with the "continuous" global section functor $\Gamma_{\text{cont}} \dashv \Spf $. Continuous here just means it remembers the topology (i.e. the filtration).

Now the definition of formal schemes feels inevitable:

> **Definition:** A **formal scheme** is an adic locally ringed space locally isomorphic to
> a formal spectrum of an adic ring. Denote the subcategory of formal schemes by $\FSch\subset \ALRS$.

This raises a problem though. There's no obvious way to turn a "formal scheme" in this sense into an ind-schemes (which are much more convenient for certain purposes). We could try to define the ind-scheme as the formal colimit over the Čech nerve of a chosen covering by formal spectra (which are themselves filtered colimits of affine schemes). However, this is probably a very bad idea since it will most likely depend on the choice of covering.

> **Question:** Can we construct a functor $\FSch \to \IndSch$ with some good properties? (Hopefully fully faithful but if not maybe at least full.) If not is there a better definition of a formal scheme which enables you to play in both worlds (ind schemes and locally ringed spaces)?

Comment: I think without finiteness hypotheses you're doomed? There's a careful discussion of this stuff in the stacks project, where they discuss what conditions you need to have this nice Ind-presentation you're looking for. http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AIT seems relevant, but I guess they don't focus much on morphisms

Comment: @DylanWilson I'm almost sure Quasi-compact + Separated (i.e. diagonal is affine in the formal sense - meaning the inverse image by the diagonal pulls back formal spectra to formal spectra) is enough since then you can really do that cech nerve thing. Maybe qcqs will do?

Comment: You can consider sheaves of sets on the Zariski site. Both schemes and formal schemes embed as a full subcategory there, affine schemes correspond to representable sheaves and any sheaf has a canonical representation as a colimit of representables. This colimit can be big in general, but for formal schemes it is small. Colimits in the presheaf category are formal, in the sheaf category they are not. I don't know if that is a problem for you. For many purposes the presheaf category is just as good. Most importantly, a presheaf has the same category of quasicoherent sheaves as sheaffification.

Comment: @AntonFetisov I don't want to sound hostile in any way but i have a naive question regarding this point of view. Recently I noticed that a considerable portion of questions I ask on this site regarding definitions of objects/categories tend to get universal answers like the working in the sheaf topos. While I don't understand this theory very well yet I'm aware of some of the advantages of this category. Is it common in recent (20 years) work in algebraic geometry to work in the sheaf topos even when treating phenonmenen concerning a specific class of objects?

Comment: @SaalHardali well, it is a universal answer after all. Any reasonable category in mathematics is accessible (otherwise I suggest it isn't reasonable), any accessible category is a full subcategory in a presheaf topos, and a topos has one of the best properties in the categorical world (all limits/colimits, local hom etc). Basically it has everything you can formally ask, and logically it is a lot like working with sets. Some categories (like derived algebraic or stable motivic) are rather hard to define without topoi.

Comment: @SaalHardali Also if you know what is ètale site then you know what a topos is, so it's very natural. Overall working with sheaves is the quickest and at the same time most efficient dirty hack for solving formal predicaments. Personally I prefer the PoV that a scheme is its monoidal stable category of QCoh sheaves, but it certainly isn't simple and doubtly more geometric.

Comment: @SaalHardali Also, a ringed topos is a general type of answer for classical modulii problems (is there any other global way to speak about orbifolds?). And the geometric picture, having its merits, quickly gets messy with details. Personally I already have trouble visualizing formal schemes. Going further, if I consider a modulii problem for formal schemes, then I should represent it by what? Topoi with local adic rings? Is it really better than sheaves?

Comment: Would you mind undeleting this question?  While no one has given an answer, I think it is an interesting question, and the voting indicates that other people agree.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I was just in the process of undeleting several questions I deleted (selfishly) almost missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Your category of adic rings seems "wrong" (what motivates your definition?). Use (pre)admissible rings as in EGA 0$_{\rm{I}}$, 7.2.1-7.2.2. Upon reading 10.5.1 and 10.6 in EGA I, the content of your question is this: does every formal scheme (in the sense of EGA) admit a fundamental system of ideals of definition? This is clearly affirmative in the locally noetherian case (see 10.6.3 and 10.6.10 in EGA I), and for the rather less evident qcqs case (as @DylanWilson suggested might work) see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AJF for an affirmative proof.

Comment: @nfdc23 I don't understand why the definition you mention isn't equivalent to the one i have given. As i think Dylan himself mentions there is no treatment for morphisms so this is not entirely a complete answer.

Comment: Reread the definition in EGA carefully.  Your definition (what motivation?) doesn't ensure powers of any ideals "converge to 0". If you read in EGA (which I strongly recommend), in particular proofs using the definition, you'll see why that definition is chosen and why your definition is too general for those proofs to work.  @DylanWilson doesn't say there is no treatment for morphisms (in EGA or the Stacks Project), only that not much is done with morphisms in extreme generality; the concept  of morphism is defined (in both places), and studied very deeply in EGA (see EGA III$_1$, section 5).

Comment: @nfcd23 Of course I was referring to the stacks project when talking about morphisms and what I meant is that they don't seem to show that there is a fully faithful. I will check the section you mention. Regarding the definition I think I'll need an counterexample or at least precise formal statement to see why these definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: The definition of (pre)admissible ring in EGA includes a condition involving powers of ideals whereas your proposed definition includes no such condition.  You can use that distinction to make many (even noetherian) examples showing the definitions are not equivalent; good exercise.  The notion you define is what EGA (and other places) call a "linearly topologized" ring (except that your notion is also Hausdorff); this is a weaker concept than what EGA defines as a (pre)"admissible" ring (which is the more appropriate notion to use).

Answer (score 4):

In Yasuda's article Non-adic formal schemes, https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0434, he redefines formal schemes as certain topological spaces equipped with a sheaf of pro-rings (as opposed to a sheaf of topological rings).

Complete linearly topologized rings embed fully faithfully into the category of pro-rings (Paragraph 5.2 of loc.cit) so maybe this is in the direction you are looking for? Admissibility is discussed in Paragraph 5.3.